# Induction of $\sum^n_{k=2} 1 - 1/k^2 =(1+n)/(2n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Can someone help me with this induction please?

$$\sum^n_{k=2} 1 - 1/k^2 ={1+n\over 2n}.$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The left hand side is greater than $n-2$ and the right hand side is $\frac12+\frac1{2n}$ which is less than $1$ for $n\gt1$. This cannot hold for many large $n$.

Comment: I have proved the base case for P(2). Using the hint of N. S. 

But i'm stack here 
 
i have replaced $\sum_{i=2}^n (1 - \frac{1}{k^2})$ with $\frac{1 + n}{2n}$ and now i have : 
$\frac{1 + 2}{2n} + 1 - \frac{1 }{(n+1)^2}$
and i have
$\frac{(1+n)^3 + 2n(n+1)^2 -2n}{2n(n+1)^2} $

Comment: Check the PS to my answer....

Comment: When n=3 the LHS is 59/36 and the RHS is 2/3, so your statement is false

Comment: Don't you think your sum needs/deserves some $(\,\,)$'s like $\left(1 - {1 \over k^{2}}\right)$. Otherwise, the answer is $n - 1 - {1 \over k^{2}}$ !!!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum^{n+1}_{k=2} 1 -\frac{1}{k^2}=\left(\sum^{n}_{k=2} 1 -\frac{1}{k^2} \right) +1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Once you fix your problem (note that the sequence on the LHS is increasing approximately ar the rate of $S_n \sim n$, while the RHS is tending to  a constant, you probably copied the problem wrong) just prove $P(2)$ and use the above formula to prove the inductive step.

P.S. Are you sure the exercise is NOT

$$\prod^{n}_{k=2}( 1 -\frac{1}{k^2})=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

if it is, note 
$$\prod^{n+1}_{k=2} (1 -\frac{1}{k^2})=(1 -\frac{1}{(n+1)^2})\prod^{n}_{k=2} (1 -\frac{1}{k^2})=(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2})\prod^{n}_{k=2} (1 -\frac{1}{k^2})
$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have proved the formula for P(2). 
Now i'm stack here 
i have replaced $\sum_{i=2}^n (1 - \frac{1}{k^2})$ with $\frac{1 + n}{2n}$ and now i have : 
$\frac{1 + 2}{2n} + 1 - \frac{1 }{(n+1)^2}$
and i have
$\frac{(1+n)^3 + 2n(n+1)^2 -2n}{2n(n+1)^2} $

Comment: @StefanB Again there is a mistake in the problem...The LHS is divergent, the RHS in your formula is convergent...Are you sure the formula is a sum, not a product? I think with product it is correct.

Comment: @N.S. I hope you don't mind: I corrected mathematical typos. See the revision history.

Comment: Thank you again yes I think that I have copied the problem wrong. With the product it makes sense. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a summation and not a product, if you enjoy generalized harmonic numbers,
$$S_n=\sum^n_{k=2}\left( 1 - \frac 1 {k^2} \right)=n-H_n^{(2)}$$ For large values of $n$, this would give
$$S_n=-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}+n+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which has little to do with $\frac{n+1}{2n}$.

It **must** be the product as already said in comments and answers.